# How to log to socket in Flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have the rest of my program using a socketHandler to log which is being consumed using http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577025-loggingwebmonitor-a-central-logging-server-and-mon/.

How do I setup my flask app to log this?

I tried the following based on their docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file):

```
class HelloWorld(Resource):

    def get(self):
        resp = "HELLO!"
        app.logger.info("GET HelloWorld %s", resp)
        return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    import logging.handlers # you NEED this line
    socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',
                        logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
    socketHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(socketHandler)

    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```